Gets 401 when trying to create an inherited process using the Azure DevOps REST API
I'm trying to create an inherited process from my Azure DevOps extension but get 401.
I've specified the vso.work_full scope and followed the instructions from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/processes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP
List processes and creating work items works fine using the REST API and I can create the process manually without any problem.
Below is the request body.
{
   "description":"Process for Product Planner integration",
   "name":"Agile Extended",
   "parentProcessTypeId":"adcc42ab-9882-485e-a3ed-7678f01f66bc",
   "referenceName":"Agile Extended"
}

Is it the wrong scope I'm using or have I missed something else?
Update: Resolved
I found out that the issue was caused by using the wrong URL. I had copied the url from an example that was incorrect. The 401 that I got instead of a 404 lead me in wrong direction during troubleshooting, something that can be good for others to check when troubleshooting the Azure DevOps REST API.

Hi @Lillvik what authentication method you use and how you get the token in your extension? When you create inherited processes manually, you are using your account. But when you do this in your extension, I am guessing you are using another identity. For example, an application registration created in Azure Tenant, if so, you will need to add this application registration to your DevOps organization and grant the permissions I mentioned below.

I can reproduce the same 401 error when only grant the vso.work_full scope.
According to the prerequisites to create an inherited process,

Permissions:

Be a member of the Project Collection Administrators group.
Have collection-level permissions such as Create process, Delete process, Edit process, or Delete a field from organization set to Allow.


You can add the identity used to call REST API to your Project Collection Administrators group.
Or, you can grant this identity with collection-level permissions Create process, Delete process, Edit process, or Delete a field from organization. Go to Organization Settings -> Permissions -> Users -> Find your target identity and click it -> assign the following permissions.

vso.work_full is the scope of the token. The permissions of the token are limited by the identity that generates it, so the identity needs to have sufficient permissions to create a process.

I'm already member of the group and with the necessary permissions. That's why I wrote that I can create the process manually. Have you tried and succeeded?

Are you trying to create the process using your account in your extension scripts?  When you create the process manually, you are using your account. But in the extension, I am not sure what authentication method you use and how you get the token.
